# Anime scene where evil creature gets prison sentence, and is placed on a microchip card, then found in the future by a kid

Tags: story-identification, anime

This is going to be a long shot and super vague, but in the early to mid 2000s I remember seeing this scene on TV. This creature was getting sentenced in the courtroom for its crimes, and got I guess shrunken down and placed on a microchip card or something like that.

The next scene fastforwards to the future, like "x years later", and this kid randomly finds it falling out of a box in his garage or in his attic. The creature was stored there and I guess it was forgotten about for all those years. It was like a sci-fi kind of anime show.

What was it?

Answer (score 4):

*Megas XLR*, "Breakout",
[Grrkek](https://megasxlr.fandom.com/wiki/Grrkek)
does that match?

> Grrkek was sealed away long ago for his crimes against the galaxy. Because no physical prison hold contain him, he was digitized and rendered immaterial, his digital essence stored inside a device resembling an old video game cartridge along with many other monsters. Grrkek was released by Coop when he was testing a new game, not knowing it was a containment cartridge

Comment: Welcome to SciFi.SE! Can you explain how this matches the details provided in the question? Answers shouldn't rely solely on links, as links tend to change or die out over time.

Comment: "Never schlomp a random cartridge found in your backyard into your MSX console. It could ruin your console and your day!"

Comment: Oh my god. This is it! I have been looking for this scene/show for over a decade if not more. Ever since I was a kid. Thank you for solving a lifelong question. I decided two days ago I was going to finally search for it as hard as I could. Thank you so much kind internet stranger. You made my day!